# SOFR OIS Curves & Zero-Coupon Variants

Tags: ois, ois-discounting, ois-swaps

Currently looking at yield curves, specifically SOFR OIS Curves, and I'm struggling to find a good explanation between a zero-coupon OIS curve and an annual coupon-pay OIS curve (both SOFR). When would one want to use a zero-coupon variety and when would want to use the coupon-pay type?

For reference, on Refinitiv, there is USDSROIS= (appears to be coupon paying) vs. 0#USDSROISZ=R (zero coupon). When might one be more useful than the other?

Comment: One benefit of the zero-coupon curve is that it is more convenient for discounting as here you can directly solve for the discount factor of a given maturity.